# Store in memory NSArray with pictures or SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

i don't completely understand the best choice in sprite kit animation;
1) Apple in "Adventure" example use this methodology, they store in memory animation as pictures in nsarray :

```
static NSArray *sSharedTouchAnimationFrames = nil;
- (NSArray *)touchAnimationFrames {
    return sSharedTouchAnimationFrames;
}

- (void)runAnimation
{
    if (self.isAnimated) {
        [self resolveRequestedAnimation];
    }
}

- (void)resolveRequestedAnimation
{
    /* Determine the animation we want to play. */
    NSString *animationKey = nil;
    NSArray *animationFrames = nil;
    VZAnimationState animationState = self.requestedAnimation;

    switch (animationState) {

        default:
        case VZAnimationStateTouch:
            animationKey = @"anim_touch";
            animationFrames = [self touchAnimationFrames];
            break;

        case VZAnimationStateUntouch:
            animationKey = @"anim_untouch";
            animationFrames = [self untouchAnimationFrames];
            break;
    }

    if (animationKey) {
        [self fireAnimationForState:animationState usingTextures:animationFrames withKey:animationKey];
    }

    self.requestedAnimation = VZAnimationStateIdle;
}

- (void)fireAnimationForState:(VZAnimationState)animationState usingTextures:(NSArray *)frames withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    SKAction *animAction = [self actionForKey:key];
    if (animAction || [frames count] < 1) {
        return; /* we already have a running animation or there aren't any frames to animate */
    }

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                         [SKAction animateWithTextures:frames timePerFrame:self.animationSpeed resize:YES restore:NO],
                                        /* [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self animationHasCompleted:animationState];
    }]*/]] withKey:key];
}
```

I appreciate this methodology, but i can't understand. Is storing SKAction in memory not better choice and use animation always like this ?

```
[self runAction:action];
```

without making always new SKAction;

```
[SKAction animateWithTextures:frames timePerFrame:self.animationSpeed resize:YES restore:NO]
```

Comment: Apple's documentation on SpriteKit is... lacking to be polite.  I have found many instances where my code is significantly shorter and sweeter than there examples.  I generally trust Ray. http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases

Comment: In ray's tutorial also this methology, when animation images is storing in NSArray

Comment: Might as well test it for performance and answer your own question.  The community could definitely benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing `SKTextures` in an `NSArray` is the recommended methodology to be used for animation. I can't say that I found SpriteKit's documentation to be lacking on the subject either, as SKAction has the method `animateWithTextures`.

You could indeed have a `SKAction` that has a given animation defined by a given `NSArray`, and maybe store those in a `NSMutableDictionary` with an animation name for a key. However this methodology I see above just has the animateTextures line of code once in their `fireAnimationState` method, and you can pass parameters to it such as the `animationState` and a `key`.

I think you would need to take more than a surface look at their methodology to determine why they chose to go this route. You can see that the `animationState` was being utilized upon completion of the animation and likely triggered something else.

`[self runAction:action]` is indeed simple, however it's also easy to see that it's not in any way managing an animationState or key, which I have to assume they decided their game needed to do.

Also keep in mind that their methodology likely has a higher level where in a given player class it's calling a flexible method for enacting an animation for a given game entity and doing other things besides just changing the animation. So in their high level coding they might be doing something more like this :

`[self runAnimation:@"jump"];`

or even

`[self jump];`

And because they have designed a low level system that manages animation states and adds keys for a given management design, they don't ever have to code the long line that you are pointing out except once in that method you see above.

A few reasons I have found it useful to store the `NSArray` of frames and not storing wrapped in a `SKAction` is because I sometimes want to manipulate the start frame of the animation or run the animation at a different speed. But you may or may not have the need to manipulate those aspects of your animation.

Comment: Thanks for describing !